# What is the name of this power connector used in the USS Yorktown?

Tags: electrical-engineering, marine-engineering

[image]
I found this in the USS Yorktown aircraft carrier (it’s open for public tours)

I know it’s a 3 phase connector of some kind, but what type of plug connects to it? Is it a nationwide standard or something specific for the ship?

In addition to the 3 phases, there’s also 3 separate holes at the top of for ground

Comment: Did you get a pic of the info on the brass plate behind? That may have helped.

Comment: @SolarMike I did not. But IIRC it said something along the lines of ‘Connected to *random jumble of numbers and letters*

Comment: Weel, it starts with "Casualty po.." and "BHD Rise..."

Comment: @SolarMike causality power terminal… and BHD riser. Sorry that’s all I have :/

Comment: well one of us can't read the brass plate... "Causality..."?

Comment: "Casualty", as in "wounded" -- I find it comforting that causality just keeps happening, without needing any power applied to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

The surface Navy had (has?) a whole set of casualty electrical power systems for use in restoring power.  This is part of those systems.  I say surface Navy because I sure don't remember this on my submarine.